# App Script: response too large for bigquery

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-bigquery

I am using google app script to automate the process of importing from BigQuery to a spreadsheet. But the app script is returning me

```
Error 413: Message: response too large
```

This is the sample of my code, and the error is on line 5

```
1 var projectId = projectid;
2 var request = {
3 query: 'My Query'
4 };
5 var queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.query(request, projectId);
```

What are some possible solutions? Are there any solutions which don't increase my BigQuery expenses?

PS: result is around 16 MB of data. i.e around 300,000 rows.

Query:

```
SELECT
  ORDER.addedon AS date,
  ORDER.display_order_id AS order_id,
  OrderSkuDetails.pid AS pid,
  OrderSkuDetails.price AS price,
  OrderSkuDetails.saleprice AS saleprice,
  OrderSkuDetails.subtotal AS subtotal,
  OrderSkuDetails.shippingcharge AS shippingcharge,
  OrderSkuDetails.codcharge AS codcharge,
  User.email AS email,
  ORDER.order_id AS payment_id,
  ORDER.payment_mode AS payment_mode,
  ORDER.source AS source,
  ORDER.user_id AS user_id,
  Payments.payment_status AS payment_status,
  User.profileJson.text,
  OrderStatus.sub_status_id AS sub_status_id,
  NProduct.featured AS featured
FROM
  FLATTEN([Mixpanel_Import.Order],payment_mode) AS ORDER
INNER JOIN
  [Mixpanel_Import.OrderSkuDetails] AS OrderSkuDetails
ON
  ORDER.order_id=OrderSkuDetails.order_id
INNER JOIN
  [Mixpanel_Import.OrderStatus] AS OrderStatus
ON
  ORDER.order_id=OrderStatus.order_id
INNER JOIN
  [Mixpanel_Import.User] AS User
ON
  ORDER.user_id=User.__key__.id
INNER JOIN
  [Mixpanel_Import.Payments] AS Payments
ON
  ORDER.order_id=Payments.order_id
INNER JOIN
  [Mixpanel_Import.NProduct] AS NProduct
ON 
  OrderSkuDetails.pid=NProduct.pid
```

Here is the code

```
function bigQuery(tableName) {
  var projectId = 'project';
  var request = {
    query: The Query
  };
  var queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.query(request, projectId); //Error on this line
  var jobId = queryResults.jobReference.jobId;
  Logger.log(jobId);
  var sleepTimeMs = 500;
  while (!queryResults.jobComplete) {
    Utilities.sleep(sleepTimeMs);
    sleepTimeMs *= 2;
    queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.getQueryResults(projectId, jobId);
  }
  while (queryResults.pageToken) {
    queryResults.concat(BigQuery.Jobs.getQueryResults(projectId, jobId, {pageToken: queryResults.pageToken}));
  }
  return queryResults;
}
```

Comment: You probably should not be trying to pull 300K rows over the wire and displaying them in your solution. I'm assuming you are building some kind of web frontend?

Comment: @polleyg It is basically for data analytics. I will need to pull so much data, Is there any way through which I can do it

Comment: And even if I Limit the results to 10000, the error remains the same.

Comment: Can you show us your query? I think there might be a sub query producing too many rows.

Comment: you should show the whole code. we need to see at which point you are getting this error. usually after you got response from is it from Jobs.query() you should get jobId from it and check for its status. Is it where you are getting that this job is done but with `response too large` error` - in this case your query sure produces more that 128 MB of data

Comment: I have added the query, though I don't know how that helps because I cannot give access to the data. :)

Comment: what happens when you run it from BigQuery Web UI?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant I don't think so it is a big query error because WebGUI displays the results properly.

Comment: And the error is on line 5, like I mentioned

Comment: from what I know about BigQuery API  - this cannot happen!! in line 5 you just taking reference to the query job. it just cannot fail the way you describe. what can happen is that when you take jobid out of that resonse  -and check respective job status - that is where you can get that error

Comment: Maybe it is not the bigquery that is failing, but app script itself as Error code for bigquery is 403: for large responses whereas the error code I get is 413 in the appscript itself.

Comment: that's why i recommend you to show your app script so we will point on your issue :o)

Comment: Added code to the question. Log for JobId is not generated.

Comment: if this really breaks on line 5 - to me - this leaves only one line to be suspect about - line 3. In your example it is scratched but are you sure everything is kosher there?

Comment: Line 3 as in the query? I gave you the query. I can run the same query on WEBGUI and If I limit the results to 10-100 , I do get the results. So Yes, everything is fine in there.

Comment: line 3 in the app script code!! and btw 413 error code is usually related to request rather than response. so it is likely that issue in line 3 where you generate request - just option for you to double check'

Comment: But the error is on response. The error clearly states response too large and it does work when I add 'LIMIT 1000 to the code'

Comment: sorry, i have exhausted my options for now :o(

Answer (score 1):

Please try adding `allowLargeResults` with value set to `true` in your job configuration.

As discussed in [Returning large query results](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/querying-data#returning_large_query_results)

> Queries that return large results take longer to execute, even if the result set is small, and are subject to additional limitations:
>
> - You must specify a destination table.
> - You can't specify a top-level `ORDER BY`, `TOP` or `LIMIT` clause. Doing so negates the benefit of using `allowLargeResults`, because the query output can no longer be computed in parallel.
> - Window functions can return large query results only if used in conjunction with a `PARTITION BY` clause.

If that doesn't work, suggested solution and ideas that might get around the problem given in the following might help too:

- [Loading a Lot of Data into Google Bigquery from Python](http://www.scriptscoop.space/t/498e1ca3f423/loading-a-lot-of-data-into-google-bigquery-from-python.html)
- GitHub - [HTTP Error 413 Request Entity Too Large](https://github.com/rackspace/php-opencloud/issues/537)

In addition to that, information regarding errors when working with BigQuery can also be found in [Troubleshooting Errors](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors).